# Elastic NEST De-serializing the wrong field

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Using ElasticSearch.Net v6.0.2

Given the Indexed item

```
   {
     "PurchaseFrequency": 76,
     "purchaseFrequency": 80 
   }
```

and the POCO Object

```
public class Product
    {
      public int PurchaseFrequency { get; set; }
    }
```

and the setting

```
this.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(x => x);
```

Nest is returning a PurchaseFrequency = 80 even though this is the wrong field.

How can I get NEST to pull the correct cased field from ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is going to be *easily* possible because [this behaviour is defined in Json.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1074), which NEST uses internally (not a direct dependency in 6.x, it's IL-merged into the assembly).

For example,

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType("{\"a\":1, \"A\":2}", new { a = 0 })
```

deserializes the anonymous type property `a` value to `2`. But

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType("{\"A\":2, \"a\":1}", new { a = 0 })
```

deserializes the anonymous type property `a` value to `1` i.e. the order of properties as they appear in the returned JSON has a bearing on the final value assigned to a property on an instance of a type.

If you can, avoid JSON property names that differ only in case. If you can't, then you'd need to [hook up the JsonNetSerializer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer) in the [NEST.JsonSerializer nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.JsonNetSerializer/) and write a custom `JsonConverter` for your type which only honours the exact casing expected.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. That makes a lot of sense.As the issue is due to Newtonsoft I'll work on re-indexing or removing the wrongly cased field.